# How to determine that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin\frac{x}{x+y}$ is homogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First time I looked up this problem, I say yes but now I'm confused.

Consider the following first order differential equation, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin\frac{x}{x+y}.$$

Substitute $v=y/x$ then it leads to the first order separable equation. Is this wrong?

---

Edit: Several years have passed now, resolving the OP as follows.

For the above equation to be well-defined, $x+y\neq0$ as long as $x$ and $y$ are not zero at the same time. If $x=0$, then the right-hand side is $0$ and if $y=0$, then the right-hand side is still constant; hence the equation is homogeneous (in the sense of 'same order'). Now substitute $y=cx$, i.e., $c=x/y$ for $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$. And then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin\frac{x}{x+y}=\sin\frac{1}{1+c}.
\end{align}
This yields the above first order ordinary differential equation is homogeneous since the right-hand side is dependent solely on $c$, not on $x$ and $y$ independently.

Comment: $\sin\frac{x}{x+y}$ is not a differential equation.

Comment: You should post the Differential equation.

Comment: I've editted my post.

Comment: If you "substitute $y=cx$", you must do it also on the left side of your ODE, $c$ being your new function of $x$. I.e. you must replace $y'$ by $c'x+c$.

Comment: Tiny mistyping: $c=y/x$, not $x/y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f(x,y)$ is homogeneous if $f(tx,ty)=t^k f(x,y)$, $k$ is any real number and is the degree of the homogeneous equation.

Here, $f(x,y)=\sin \left(\dfrac{x}{x+y} \right)$. Now $f(tx,ty)=\sin \left(\dfrac{tx}{t(x+y)} \right)=\sin \left(\dfrac{x}{x+y} \right)$.

Hence the function $\sin \left(\dfrac{x}{x+y} \right)$ is homogeneous.